# What is the max length for key in Elasticache Memcached?

Tags: java, memcached, amazon-elasticache

We use elasticache-java-cluster-client-1.0.61.0.jar for connecting to Elasticache Memcached client. I noticed that there is restriction in code on max length for key - 250 bytes. Is it possible to overwrite it in both client and Memcached?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

memcached limits the key length to 250 bytes. The only way to change that is by modifying memcached.h and recompiling. Of course you cannot recompile your memcached on ElastiCache.

The common pattern is for you to hash (say with SHA1) your keys. Actually, some memcached clients do this for you by default.

Or consider moving to [Amazon ElastiCache for Redis](https://aws.amazon.com/elasticache/redis/), Redis has a max key size of 512MB.